# How to allow asynchronous control using the mouse in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, game-engine

I am relatively new to C# and even newer to asynchronous programing. I am working on a simple 2D game from scratch (and in the process writing my own game engine) using Windows Forms and seemed to have hit a snag with my asynchronous programming for movement. Though this code was intended for game use, I hope to use asynchronous processing for work purposes which was part of the reason I started programming this for fun in my off-time. Originally my movement was synchronous and worked perfectly, but I wanted to be able to change the movement destination mid-travel and couldn't do that synchronously. I have been trying to convert the synchronous method to asynchronous using various posts here and the official Microsoft documentation but so far have not had any luck getting it to work as expected. I have tried to reduce the code and clean it up as much as I possibly could without obscuring the problem. Below are the details of what I expect the code to do and a summary of the problems.

**What is expected of the code?**

The only current intent of the code in question is the accept a right click from the mouse on the window and move a "unit" from its current location to the location clicked while still allowing you to click in the window to change the location as needed (think RTS-style movement).

**What is the problem I have been having?**

I only have guesses as to the root cause of my problem with this code, but the symptoms are that after executing the method for movement just a few times the program slows before finally freezing. I ran it through debug and I noticed that the ram usage slowly crept up with each use and each use would significantly increase the CPU usage reaching 100% in just a few clicks. The movement itself works fine, but the system just bogs down making it unusable.

**What I have done to try to remedy the problem?**

I have rewritten a majority of the movement code during the conversion to asynchronous 3 times in an attempt to get this to work. I have a complete history for the project if anyone wants to see what was changed between these versions. I went from using a background worker which caused cross-threading exceptions to implementing a primitive version of the current task which had disposing issues and the cancellation process didn't work to finally this code. I assumed the increasing CPU and ram usage were due to the task not disposing properly and added the dispose commands, but that really didn't seem to help much. I have tried making as much as I could static so that it shouldn't be able to duplicate itself, but that had no effect. I have been working on this one issue alone for a few weeks now and have not been able to find an answer that corrects my problem.

## Code

**Summary**

Below is a quick summary list of what the code does, including removed code.

1. Create the "play field" (blank white form that takes up the whole window) and units (32px colored square picturebox).
2. Upon clicking on the "Good Guy" set him as selected.
3. Upon clicking on the "play field" move the selected unit to the clicked location using an asynchronous task.
4. Upon finishing the task dispose of unneeded resources.

**Calling Mouse Click Event and Receiving Method**

```
// Mouse click event for moving the "Good Guy" to the clicked location on the play field.

playField.MouseClick += (sender1, e1) => PlayFieldOnMouseClickAsync(e1, goodGuy, loopRunning);


// The receiving method for the mouse click event handler.
private static async void PlayFieldOnMouseClickAsync(MouseEventArgs e1
                                                   , Control playerUnit
                                                   , bool loopRunning) {
    switch (e1.Button) {    
// Right click only moves selected units.
        case MouseButtons.Right:
            if (!UnitSelected) return;

// The variables needed for moving units.
            var MoveDistance = new Point(MousePosition.X - playerUnit.Location.X, MousePosition.Y - playerUnit.Location.Y);
            var speedX            = 1;
            var speedY            = 1;
            var moveNegativeXFlag = false;
            var moveNegativeYFlag = false;
            var movementLoopTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

// These two checks determine if the unit needs to be moved positively or negatively along the play field before converting the distance to its absolute value for easy math manipulation later.
            if (moveDistance.X < 0) {
                speedX            = -1;
                moveNegativeXFlag = true;
            }

            if (moveDistance.Y < 0) {
                speedY            = -1;
                moveNegativeYFlag = true;
            }

            moveDistance.X = Math.Abs(moveDistance.X);
            moveDistance.Y = Math.Abs(moveDistance.Y);

// If the loop is already running then this cancels the loop before starting a new loop.
            if (loopRunning) {
                movementLoopTokenSource.Cancel();
            }

// This toggles the state of running loop flag but may not work on subsequent runs if the loop doesn't finish.
            loopRunning = !loopRunning;
            var loopCancellationToken = movementLoopTokenSource.Token;

// Prepares the movement task to be called.
            var movementLoop = MovementLoopTask(loopCancellationToken
                                              , speedX   
                                              , speedY
                                              , moveNegativeXFlag
                                              , moveNegativeYFlag
                                              , playerUnit
                                              , moveDistance);

// Starts the movement loop and upon finish sets the flag back and disposes unneeded items.
            await movementLoop;
            loopRunning = false;
            movementLoop.Dispose();
            movementLoopTokenSource.Dispose();
            break;
    }
}
```

**Movement Performing Task**

```
// After being called this asynchronously performs movement for the selected unit.
public static async Task MovementLoopTask(
                                          CancellationToken loopCancellationToken
                                        , int               speedX
                                        , int               speedY
                                        , bool              moveNegativeXFlag
                                        , bool              moveNegativeYFlag
                                        , Control           playerUnit
                                        , Point             moveDistance) {
// An in-line call for the creating a loop task.
    await Task.Run(async () => {
        while (true) {
            await Task.Delay(10);
            loopCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

// This is the actual loop that performs the moving by running both switchs until no more movement is needed.
            if (speedX != 0 || speedY != 0) {
                playerUnit.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => playerUnit.Location = new Point(playerUnit.Location.X + speedX 
                                                                                 , playerUnit.Location.Y + speedY)));

// This switch checks the X distance and stops X movement upon reaching the desired location by setting the movement speed to 0.
                switch (moveNegativeXFlag) {
                    case false when moveDistance.X > 16:
                        moveDistance.X -= Math.Abs(speedX);
                        break;

                    case false:
                        speedX = 0;
                        break;

                    default:
                        if (moveDistance.X > -16)
                            moveDistance.X -= Math.Abs(speedX);
                        else
                            speedX = 0;
                            break;
                }

// This switch checks the Y distance and stops Y movement upon reaching the desired location by setting the movement speed to 0.
                switch (moveNegativeYFlag) {
                    case false when moveDistance.Y > 16:
                        moveDistance.Y -= Math.Abs(speedY);
                        break;

                    case false:
                        speedY = 0;
                        break;

                    default:
                        if (moveDistance.Y > -16)
                            moveDistance.Y -= Math.Abs(speedY);
                        else
                            speedY = 0;
                            break;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
       }
   }
 , loopCancellationToken);
}
```

**Results after edit:**

The code now has improved but still has issues. The program no longer slows down and maxes the CPU usage unless you click really fast. The ram still has a slowly increasing creep. If you click, it works asynchronously, but fails to cancel the previous movement and they just overlap (E.G if you click multiple times in the same spot it moves faster and if you click once in direct opposite directions it will sit there until you give another click so that one can overcome the other.)

Comment: Two points -  1) Check if  you are subscribing `MouseClick` event on `PlayField` multiple times during the course of flow? 2)  Use the `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`. Also, put a await Task.Delay(10) in while loop to validate what happens if Thread is freed for some time. 10 is an arbitary number, which you set it based on your analysis or Don't use if not require.

Comment: Have you validated the point 1 --- multiple event subscriptoin?

Comment: @user1672994 I made the following changes (I'll edit the question to reflect this) but it still has problems I'll describe: 


1. Changed `Invoke` to `BeginInvoke`.
2. Added `await Task.Delay(10);` to the beginning of the `while` loop.
3. Because point 2 required it I added `async` before the lambda expression for the `Task.Run`

Comment: Also, I don't see any break condition for while loop. will the routine ever come out of while loop?

Comment: @user1672994 I did verify the multiple event subscription and it was fine. You are correct that I don't have a proper `break` for the `while` loop, I had it in my previous revision but probably lost it when I was trying some sample code for cancelling tasks. EDIT: After adding the `break` as shown in the edited code everything remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @user1672994 I found out why everything was broken. I needed to make the following changes to the code to get it to work:

1. In the main method I initialized the `loopRunning` variable to `false` and for reasons still unknown to me it would reset it to `false` with every mouse click event. So to correct this I just made it a property.
2. At the beginning of the loop I changed `playerUnit.Invoke` to `playerUnit.BeginInvoke`.
3. I added an `else` statement with a `break` for the while loop.
4. I had to change the `while` loop condition because it wouldn't cancel when the exception was thrown so I just use the `loopRunning` variable for the condition now.
5. Finally, though I'm still in the process of completing this, a new `CancellationTokenSource()` needed to be used if a cancellation is called.